# Bluemix DashDB not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

My DashDB is not working. When I try to open it, it shows me the error:

"The server refused the connection."

What could be wrong? Is it a problem with bluemix or there's something wrong with my network settings? Help!

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? I see DashDB access through browser using port 8443 instead of regular 443, which might not be allowed by an enterprise firewall.

Comment: I guess it was an issue with my organisations network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the status page to see if IBM dashDB is undergoing maintenance : http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus 
In this case: Maintenance: IBM dashDB Web Console - April 23rd, 1 AM AEST (April 22nd, 11 AM US EDT / 15:00 UTC) - AU-SYD region
IBM dashDB Web Console will undergo maintenance from 1:00 - 2:00 AM AEST on April 23rd. During this period, the service will be unavailable.

If the issue is still there after the window maintenence, use the Support Widget to open a ticket. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form. 
 Or
use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.